# I need to Create a custom Branded library for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, branding

Customer is asking for a Tile design for a Sharepoint 2010 Library in a 4x4 block, the 1st set of Tiles will be Folders when clicked on they want another set of sub-file tiles to open up and then apon the 3rd click actualy see the docs in a tile format. The hard part is going to be when they add new folders they want them to be added as tiles. Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

Comment: sorry, but this question really is way to broad... start working on it, and post a question if you run into trouble.

Comment: Sounds like a custom Web Part to display things as you want.

Comment: I should rephrase what I need, Im trying to change the class Tag on the documents in the document library. As of right now I can change the tag but not the positioning. When I change the positioning and open it in Sharepoint the files end up stacked on top of each other because they all have the same class tag. Is the only way to make the change to Hard code it? Or is there a way to do it through CSS Html?

Answer (score 1):

Tell the customer SharePoint isn't Lotus Notes.